# How to run Conv3D Model in Android?

Tags: android, python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-lite

I've recently delved into the Computer Vision and Deep Learning world. I developed a 3D CNN model for action recognition in Keras and now I'm interested in running it in Android (Java). The layers I'm using are Conv3D and MaxPool3D. The total size of the model is 40MB

I've been looking for solutions in the tensorflow-lite space but it seems that they don't have the operations implemented yet.

I got the following error when using the converter.convert() function to get the tflite model

```
ConverterError: TOCO failed. See console for info.
2019-05-05 14:39:07.006669: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: Conv3D
```

So what can I do to be able to run it in Java? Should I:

- run .pb file directly? I don't even know if this is possible now (after tflite). If so, how much time would a new-gen smartphone take to run a 40MB file?
- implement ops by myself? If so, how to?
- try different approach outside tensorflow?
- implement a new action recognition architecture that uses only tflite supported ops
- other

I didn't find any Conv3D implementation in Android so far in the web... 
Thank you so much for your attention!

Comment: What is the nature and shape of your training data?

Comment: The input data is a clip of 10 processed frames. I only want to run predictions in the Android device

Answer (score 0):

- If you want to execute as standalon JAVA code using tensorflow,
  please have a look on
  [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/lang_java). But if you
  want to implement something for android using JAVA, the only way is using
  [Tensorflow Lite](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite).
- For infernece time, you can compare your model with some of the state of art architecure in performance benchmarks. You can find [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/benchmarks) benchmark values , it shows the comparison with Pixel 2 and Pixel XL device.
- For your implementation of Conv3D, if you want to implement ops, you can have look on   [custom operators](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/ops_custom).
- I would prefere your suggestion of 'implement a new action recognition architecture that uses only tflite supported ops'. [Here](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/ops_compatibility) you can find list of supported operations using TF Lite.